# How to get the formData of a very long long form

Tags: forms, next.js, server-action

I'm currently working with a very long form in NextJS, i have known about the server action recently and trying to do something about form and mutate data with it,it just give some example about handle server action like:

```
  const handleCreate = async (formData: FormData) => {
    "use server";
    const rawFormData = {
      id: formData.get("id"),
    };
    // Send rawFormData and do something ....
  };
```

But the problem is when i have a very long form, how can i make the rawFormData without doing something like:

```
    const rawFormData = {
      id: formData.get("id"),
      name: formData.get("name"),
      address: formData.get("address"),
      gender: formData.get("gender"),
      // many many fields
      dob: formData.get("dob"),
    };
```

I have tried a dummy approach by passing an array of fields in the form and doing like this

```
  const handleCreate = async (formData: FormData,fields: any[]) => {
    "use server";

    let rawFormData: any = {};
    fields.forEach((field: any) => (rawFormData[field] = formData.get(field)));
    // Fetch and do something ....
  };
```

But it leading to another error say that NextJS does not allow to pass anything into action except formData
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Show your `<form>`. Handling forms without form?

Comment: I think I got it. You want to process the data of a large form. Probably converting it to a plan object or iterating over fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try refreshing and doing something and finally find a way to do that by passing the props to the parent component and then pass it to the children like this:

```
const ParentComponent = ({fields}:{field:any[]}) => {

    const handleCreate = async (formData: FormData) => {
        "use server";
        let rawFormData: any = {};
        fields.forEach((field: any) => (rawFormData[field] = formData.get(field)));
        // Fetch and do something ....
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

I did not check the following code. Report, if it does what you want. Otherwise, you can always resort to the other `FormData` methods.

```
const plainObject = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but maybe that not the problem about what im doing, i think its about the way i pass the form field to the components